# Any idea why my carousel items are not showing up?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, carousel

I am trying display a carousel of images on my page, but it is not displaying the images at all. when I console logged the image url, it is there, but no image at all.

also one more question, what would I use for the key here? I used the image url here as the key

```
import galleryStyles from "../styles/Gallery.module.css";
import Carousel from "react-bootstrap/Carousel";

const BigGallery = ({ images }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <div>hi </div>
      <Carousel interval={4000} className={galleryStyles.Carousel}>
        {images.map((image) => {
          console.log(image.url); // This logged the correct url
          <Carousel.Item key={image.url}>
            <img src={image.url} className={galleryStyles.image} />
          </Carousel.Item>;
        })}
      </Carousel>
    </>
  );
};

export default BigGallery;
```

Comment: Your `images.map(...)` callback function doesn't have a return value.

Comment: Thanks this works, when using this do I always have to have a return statement? I used this in another part of my project and I didnt have a return statement there

Comment: You probably used `(image) => (...JSX...)` instead of `(image) => { ...JSX... }` notice the difference `(` and `)` vs `{` and `}`. When using curly brackets with an arrow function you'll start a block, which allows you to write multiple statements as part of the block contents. When using parentheses you're passing a single expression which has an implicit return value. See: [Arrow function expressions: Function body - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#function_body)

Comment: `(image) => { return <JSX /> }` (explicit return) is the same as `(image) => <JSX />` (implicit return), but can also be written with parentheses ([grouping operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Grouping)) `(image) => (<JSX />)`. This is often done so `<JSX />` can be placed on a separate line, because a newline directly after `=>` without starting a block or expression is not allowed.

Comment: Thanks,  that's exactly how it was , my other function had a () instead of curly